# What is a wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I read about Erwin Schrödinger describing wave particle duality with something called a [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function). What does a wave function mean?

Comment: To what extent does [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) not answer your question?  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So before we get into this there is a few levels of explanation to this and as this seems to be one of your first encounters with the subject I will skimp on mathematical details and rigor and keep the discussion rather shallow. If you are interested in a more detailed account let me know.

So first of all let us quickly recap how we normally describe an object, say a particle in classical physics:

Assuming the particle itself has no internal structure ( or spin for that matter) we can describe how the particle behaves by looking at its position $x(t)$ as a function of time $t$. So at each time, we can look at this function and it tells us where we will find our particle. Of course the hard bit if figuring out what this function actually looks like which we normally do by using the equation of motion of the particle if we know the forces acting on it. (Thing along the lines of $F = ma$ which gives a differential equation for $x(t)$.)

Now when we move to quantum mechanics however things are not as simple anymore. You might have heard of the idea that in Quantum mechanics the notion of a point particle as we used before is not really sensible anymore as a particle is no longer at any single point in space but rather "smeared" out across a region of space. This behavior is exactly what is captured by the wavefunction. A wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ of a particle now no longer only depends on time but also depends on space. Roughly speaking we can look at this function plug in a point in space and a time and the value of the function will tell us what the probability is to find our particle there if we were to e.g. place a detector there. (Actually, the probability is given by $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ but the intuition still holds).

So that is what the Wavefunction actually is. Now one question you might ask is why can't we write down something like this for a classical particle? The answer is that we can however the function will be trivial in the sense that it is $1$ along the path $x(t)$ and $0$ everywhere else, because out trajectory $x(t)$ is unique if we know all the forces and the initial conditions in our problem.
Now you might wonder why the converse does not work. Why can't we just write down something like $x(t)$ for our quantum particle if we know all the forces etc.? The answer is connected to a different concept in Quantum mechanics called Heisenbergs uncertainty principle, which roughly tells us that there is no way to both restrict the initial position and momentum of the particle to a single value at the same time. Thus the path the particle will take is no longer unique but rather a smeared out function.

So to recap:
A wavefunction is a function which tells us (approximately) what the probability is to find a particle at a certain point $x$ and time $t$.

Answer (score 0):

A [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) is a mathematical description of a quantum system. It is a complex valued function of time $t$ and of the possible states of the system. The squared amplitude of the system's wave function gives the probability that a measurement of the system at time $t$ will give a particular result.

The "wave" part of the name comes from the fact that wave functions of simple quantum systems are often periodic in time, in space, or in some other parameter of the system being described, or are a linear combination of such periodic functions.